# Отличия прямой от косвенной речи

Tags: пунктуация

"Когда-то люди были ростом с Кинг-Конга, уверяют некоторые ученые" — нужно ли как-то пунктуационно выделять уверение ученых, кроме запятой, как приведено тут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, который приведен вами, вполне правильный, так как *"уверяют некоторые ученые"* выступает в качестве вводной конструкции. Кавычки не нужны в таком случае. 
Конечно, можно оформить иначе, например: 
"Когда-то люди были ростом с Кинг-Конга",- уверяют некоторые ученые.  
Некоторые ученые уверяют, что когда-то люди были ростом с Кинг-Конга.  
etc.  
Лично мне больше нравится приведенный вами пример, так как в нём всё немного проще и доступнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ну у Вас не только запятые. Вы еще и кавычки поставили.

Прямая речь (речь, переданная дословно):

*"Когда-то люди были ростом с Кинг-Конга,"- уверяют некоторые ученые.* (Прямая речь в кавычках, от слов автора отделяет запятая и тире)

Косвенная речь (сложноподчиненное предложение):

*Некоторые ученые уверяют, что когда-то люди были ростом с Кинг-Конга.*